# Pandas manipulation with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large table of data containing `play_id`, `position` and `frame` columns.

- `play_id` - refers to a particular play
- `position` - either A or B (with 3 total players (rows) for each given play - any combination of As and Bs)
- `frame` - time frame (e.g. imagine freeze-frame every 1 second)

The following shows example data (simplified for clarity):

| play_id | position | frame |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2 |

I want to count the number of players in each position for each play_id (they are consistent across frames for a given play_id) and append a number to each to make them unique.

This would result in the following:

| play_id | position | frame |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A_1 | 1 |
| 1 | A_2 | 1 |
| 1 | B_1 | 1 |
| 1 | A_1 | 2 |
| 1 | A_2 | 2 |
| 1 | B_1 | 2 |
| 2 | A_1 | 1 |
| 2 | B_1 | 1 |
| 2 | B_2 | 1 |
| 2 | A_1 | 2 |
| 2 | B_1 | 2 |
| 2 | B_2 | 2 |

In reality I have 7 different positions, 25 frames and around 500,000 play_ids (along with many more columns).

How can I achieve this in an efficient manner? I assume `groupby` should be used, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby.cumcount`, to group by all columns and add a count for the positions:

```
df['position'] = df.position.str.cat(df.groupby(['play_id','frame','position']).position
                                       .cumcount().add(1).astype(str), 
                                     sep='_')

print(df)

    play_id position  frame
0         1      A_1      1
1         1      A_2      1
2         1      B_1      1
3         1      A_1      2
4         1      A_2      2
5         1      B_1      2
6         2      A_1      1
7         2      B_1      1
8         2      B_2      1
9         2      A_1      2
10        2      B_1      2
11        2      B_2      2
```